# Clojure "and" macro as a symbol

Tags: clojure

Why do the following statements return different results?  And further, how would one write the second statement to receive the expected result of false?

```
(clojure.core/and false true)
=> false

((resolve 'clojure.core/and) false true)
=> true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind folks at #clojure on freenode helped me with an answer.
First, one should try to avoid resolving macros at run-time.
Second, the macro function is implemented as a function that takes in two parameters, besides of the any (&) args.  Hence, the correct way to write the second statement above would be

```
((resolve 'clojure.core/and) nil nil false true) => 
**(clojure.core/let [and__3973__auto__ false] (if and__3973__auto__ (clojure.core/and true) and__3973__auto__))**
```

Since we are still using a macro, it simply will expand it to code, instead of returning an actual value.
The reason AND is implemented as a macro, is to make short-circuiting possible.
You can see from the REPL:

```
(defmacro and
  "Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
  returns logical false (nil or false), and returns that value and
  doesn't evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns
  the value of the last expr. (and) returns true."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
   `(let [and# ~x]
      (if and# (and ~@next) and#))))
```

Without the macro, an AND function would evaluate all of the predicate given to it without short-circuiting.
In my particular case, this is exactly what I needed; both for AND and OR non short-circuiting functions.
Here follows both functions in case anyone ever needs them:

```
(defn and* [& xs] (every? identity xs))
(defn or* [& xs] (not= (some true? xs) nil))
```